# How do I perform a mutation with the guarantee that the subscription is ready?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, graphql-subscriptions, prisma-graphql

Previously, in the GraphQL protocol there was a special message confirming the subscription: SUBSCRIPTION_SUCCESS (server -> client). Now it is deprecated: [here in apollographql](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws/blob/4e3a6efeb1d038aa31d847707f4efdb4927a9a2b/src/server.ts#L408) and [here in prismagraphql](https://github.com/prismagraphql/prisma/blob/1887ec62bcbc6966c069df2fa446dcf7173056d2/server/servers/subscriptions/src/main/scala/com/prisma/subscriptions/protocol/SubscriptionProtocol.scala#L121). Why is it no longer necessary?

I am subscribing, for example

`subscription commentAdded {
  commentAdded(repoFullName: "test"){
    id
  }
}`

and I immediately perform a mutation,

`mutation submitComment {
  submitComment(repoFullName: "test", commentContent: "test_msg") {
    id
    content
  }
}`

As I understand these two actions are performed asynchronously. And the subscription processing on the server and the creation of the [Source Event Stream](https://github.com/facebook/graphql/blob/master/spec/Section%206%20--%20Execution.md#executing-operations) can take some time. How a client can be sure that a mutation will trigger this subscription? Or... Should all mutation requests to the server wait until the subscription is completed?